# d3.js, how can i create an axis with custom labels and customs ticks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have an array similar to this:

```
[{year: 1999, val: 5}, {year: 2002, val: 8}]
```

and I would like to add an axis where I have one tick for each year value (something I can do with tickValues and tickFormat) but where the tick label is not only the year but has a custom format, so the result could be something like "1999: 5" for the first array element.

To rephrase it:

Where I'm now

```
const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)
        .tickValues(data.map(d => d.year);
```

This is not ok because only the year is visualized on the label of the tick and I would like to use a custom format.

Is this possible with d3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try like this

```
const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)
        .tickValues(data)
        .tickFormat(d => (d.year +":"+ d.val));
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote one wrong piece of code that I have now corrected. This solution (as the one I wrote before) cannot work because the elements of the array that are used for the ticks are not numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't show the scale in your question we don't know what type of scale you have and what are the domain values. But one thing is sure: you cannot pass the whole object to it. Therefore, your `tickFormat` doesn't have access to one of the properties in each object.

A simple solution is using the index of the tick to get the other property, provided that you are displaying **all** the ticks (and that you are using an ordinal scale):

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return d + ": " + data[i].val;
  });
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 100);

var data = [{
  year: 1999,
  val: 5
}, {
  year: 2002,
  val: 8
}, {
  year: 2005,
  val: 1
}, {
  year: 2008,
  val: 4
}, {
  year: 2011,
  val: 9
}, {
  year: 2014,
  val: 2
}];

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.year
  }));

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return d + ": " + data[i].val;
  });

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, we posted together the same solution! It's a bit ugly but it's the best I've been able to figure out.

Comment: @heapOverflow Our solutions **are not the same**. Your solution will show only the `val` value on the ticks, and in your question you clearly ask for the `year` and `val` in the ticks. Since you said that *it works*, I can only assume that your question is not correctly worded... that being the case, nobody can help you as the desired outcome is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

What I have been able to do now:

```
d3.axisTop(xScale)
        .tickValues(data.map(d => d.year))
        .tickFormat((d, i) => data[i].val);
```

Quite ugly but it works. If I get a better solution I will accept a different one.