# How to add custom tick labels in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add custom tick labels on the x axis,like 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 in this pattern. But the code that I am using doesn't show the decreasing numbers.

```
var margin = {
    top: 100,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 100
},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
    .rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.call(xAxis);
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it works for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872048/d3-js-how-can-i-create-an-axis-with-custom-labels-and-customs-ticks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Little hack it needed to solve this issue.

**Cause**

- d3.scale.ordinal(), domain calculation in purely mathematical logic. Each 
  domain associated with a range. ( f(x)=y ).
- Duplication not allowed because it will make ambiguity

**Solution**

- Create linear scale with total item in the axis as domain [0, itemLength]
- While creating axis use tickFormat to find out the index of the element

```js
var margin = {
 top: 100,
 right: 100,
 bottom: 100,
 left: 100
},
width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xdata = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0"];

var linear = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, 10])
 .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(linear)
 .orient("bottom");

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(linear)
 .orient("top")
 .ticks(10)
 .tickFormat(function (d) {
  return xdata[d];
 });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.call(axis);
```

```css
.axis path, line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```