# y axis vertical the range is auto ticked as 5 even if i changed to different number

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The Y axis value ranges as 0,7,14,21,28 i want to add color to 0-7 very low, 7-14 low, 14-21 medium, 21-28 high. But while append axis is auto taking range 5 for ticks.

I have already tried this link [How to add custom tick labels in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918368/how-to-add-custom-tick-labels-in-d3-js)

```
// Add the y Axis
  var ydata = ["0", "7", "14", "21", "28"];
  svg.append("g")
  .call(
    d3.axisLeft(y)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        console.log(ydata[d]);
        return ydata[d];
      })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom, values add there is a function in d3 called tickValues below is the code which solves the problem.

```
 var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues([0,7,14,21,28]);
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis").call(yAxis);
```